# how to append text to an attribute like Value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I need to append for example REL attribute of an element to value of another element.
my HTML is :

```
<div class="chkbxs">
    <input type="checkbox" for="" id="chkbx_1" rel="ABC" />
    <input type="checkbox" for="" id="chkbx_2" rel="DEF" />
</<div>
<div class="txtinpts">
    <input type="text" id="txt_1" value="" />
</div>
```

my jquery codes:

```
$(function(){
    $('.chkbxs input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
        var eachChkbxRel = $('.chkbxs input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('rel');
        $('.txtinpts input[type="text"]').attr('value', eachChkbxRel);
    });

});
```

I need to append each checked checkbox REL to text input VALUE. and if checkbox is not checked, remove it from VALUE !
also I need to separate each value with ';' .
My code above doesn't work because it only copies the last REL into the VALUE, I don't know how to fix it. anybody knows how to ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd simplify all this, using such a convenient jQuery function as [**$.map**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
$('.txtinpts input[type=text]').val(
    $.map($('.chkbxs input:checkbox:checked'), function(el) { 
        return el.getAttribute('rel') }
    ).join(',')
);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GR8AN/).

---

... but I feel there's more than that in this question actually: you probably need to adjust the text value (based on checkings) dynamically. Here's one way to do that:

```
$(function(){
    var $textInput = $('.txtinpts input[type=text]'),
        $checkboxes = $('.chkbxs input[type=checkbox]');

    $checkboxes.change(function() {
        var rels = $.map($checkboxes, function(el) {
          return el.checked ? el.getAttribute('rel') : undefined });
        $textInput.val(rels.join(','));
    });
    $checkboxes.trigger('change');
});
```

I've prepared [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dcanz/) of that too. )

Answer (score 3):

Use `this` to target only the current text box

```
var eachChkbxRel = $('.chkbxs input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('rel');
```

should be

```
var eachChkbxRel = $(this).attr('rel');
```

And try using `id` as a selector when you have one as it is faster. You can use `map` and `filter` method to get your work done.

```
$(function(){
    var $chkboxes = $('#chkbx_1, #chkbx_2'),
        $textbox  = $('#txt_1');
    // Cache your selectors

    // Bind a change event to checkbox
    $chkboxes.change(function() {
        // Filter only checkboxes that are checked
        var arr = $chkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
           return $(this).attr('rel')
        });
        // If length of object -- Then join the oject
        var value = arr.length > 0 ? arr.get().join('') : '';

        //$textbox.attr('value', value);
        $textbox.val(value);
    });
}).change();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/bjHF7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just concat the current value of the textbox with `eachChkbxRel`, and you can use `.val` to set an inputs value instead of using the `.attr`, also use the ID of the textbox instead of the lengthy selector you are currently using, and `this` for the current checkbox in the loop.

```
$(function(){
    $('.chkbxs input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
        var curInputVal = $('#txt_1').value();
        var eachChkbxRel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#txt_1').val(curInputVal+";"+eachChkbxRel);
    });

});
```